# Invocation of init method failed only from maven test ested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, autowired

I have a spring application

a new code I have inserted - fail the maven test - but only from maven
when I run the test from intelliJ the test succeeded. From maven/jenkins failed

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'predefinedModelHandlerService': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'predefinedModelHandlerService': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

I understand that it relates to the init method - in my service class i have an init method - and a static block - the weird thing that running manually test i see that the test succeeded i am able to start application and deploy it
but the test fails to start

```
static {
    for (CompanyEnumMeasurement m : CompanyEnumMeasurement.values()) {
      someList.put(m.name(), CompanyMeasurement.createFrom(m));
    }
    someList = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(someList);
}

  @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

      for (EnummyDescriptor.CompanyEnummy myType : EnummyDescriptor.CompanyEnummy.values()) {
        myDataFull.put(myType.name(), generatemy(myType.name(), false));
        myDataDimensionOnly.put(myType.name(), generatemy(myType.name(), true));
      }
      myDataFull =  Collections.unmodifiableMap(myDataFull);
      myDataDimensionOnly = Collections.unmodifiableMap(myDataDimensionOnly);
  }
```

what could be causing the init to fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6874

A known bug , probably relates to the unmodifiable self pointing .